# How do I make my app appear in app chooser?

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent

I want to advertise that my app is capable of viewing pdf files so that it will appear in the app chooser when a pdf file is selected from the file manager.

Here is what my intent filters look like

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Whenever I open a pdf from file manager it automatically selects another pdf app called Polaris Viewer.

I checked to make sure that Polaris is not the default app, under application settings. It says no defaults set.

Also, I downloaded an third party app called Intent Intercept. If I select a pdf file from file manager an app chooser appears showing Polaris and Intent Intercept. If I choose Intent Intercept it tells me that both Polaris and my app (Rollout PdfEditor) match the intent. Here is the output from Intent Interceptor:

> ACTION: android.intent.action.VIEW
>
> DATA: file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/download.pdf
>   TYPE: application/pdf
>
> FLAGS:
>         FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT
>         FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP
>
> EXTRAS:
>   EXTRA 1:
>   Class: java.lang.Boolean
>   Key: preview
>   Value: false
>   EXTRA 2:
>   Class: java.lang.String
>   Key: key_filename
>   Value: /storage/sdcard0/Download/download.pdf
>   EXTRA 3:
>   Class: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri
>   Key: android.intent.extra.STREAM
>   EXTRA 4:
>   Class: java.lang.Integer
>   Key: sort_order
>   Value: 0
>
> 2 ACTIVITIES MATCH THIS INTENT:
>   Polaris Viewer 4.1 (com.infraware.polarisviewer4 - com.infraware.polarisoffice4.OfficeLauncherActivity)
>   Rollout PdfEditor (com.example.rolloutpdfeditor - com.example.rolloutpdfeditor.MainActivity) >

Comment: Is it possible that Polaris Viewer is just your default app for such `Intents`? Go to Settings -> Apps -> Polaris Viewer and under "Launch By Default" click on "Clear Defaults".

Comment: As I said in the post, it says "No defaults set". The clear defaults button is not clickable.

Comment: Well have you tested it on another device? If your `Activity` matches the `Intent` and the other is not the default than a picker dialog should be shown.

Comment: Tried it on another device with the same result. Only this time it was Adobe Reader rather than Polaris. Once again Adobe Reader has no defaults set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing required `<category />` tags from your `IntentFilter`! if you look at the documentation for `<category />` it says:

> Note: In order to receive implicit intents, you must include the
>   CATEGORY_DEFAULT category in the intent filter. The methods
>   startActivity() and startActivityForResult() treat all intents as if
>   they declared the CATEGORY_DEFAULT category. If you do not declare it
>   in your intent filter, no implicit intents will resolve to your
>   activity.

So you always have to include `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` as category for the `IntentFilter` to work at all. If you want you app to be able to handle pdf links from a browser or other apps you also need to include `android.intent.category.BROWSABLE`. You can find documentation about `BROWSABLE` [**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Building). It reads:

> **CATEGORY_BROWSABLE**
>   The target activity allows itself to be started by a web browser to display data referenced by a link — such as an image or an e-mail message.

Try this `IntentFilter`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
</intent-filter>
```

I think you are missing those two categories.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I did not realize that categories were necessary to match an intent. Ill have to read up more.

Comment: Yes categories are important when you want those things to work. You can find more information [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and [**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html). I am glad I could help!

Comment: Please don't forget to accept this answer! This indicates to other people that this was the answer which solved your problem! As a little reward we both get reputation from that!

Comment: How did you figure out what categories that particular intent was using?

Comment: That's the tricky part. Most often you can look it up in the documentation. Or somewhere else on the internet, but getting the more obscure `Intents` to work can be quite difficult. But in this specific case I look at the documentation for `<category />` [**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/category-element.html) and it pretty much tells you that you **ALWAYS** have to include `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` for the `IntentFilter` to work at all. `android.intent.category.BROWSABLE` is just so your app can also handle links from browser etc.