# Whether there is anyway to bypass the browser chooser for urls in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to bypass the browser chooser for urls and open specific urls with my app.

Let us an on a APP "A" user tries to open youtube links; The links should open with my app instead of allowing the user to go through browser chooser.

whether it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to "bypass" the `Chooser` for URLs. If you own a valuable URL (like "www.google.com" or "www.youtube.com" - as you mention) and an app could register any URL to "bypass" the browser, I think a lot of people would be unhappy - both users and Google in many cases - even if in your specific case, the users would be fine with it.

You can, however, become an *option* in the `Chooser`...

The `Chooser` selects apps based on `IntentFilter` setup for Activities - check out this posts:

[How do I make my app appear in app chooser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021580/how-do-i-make-my-app-appear-in-app-chooser)

Comment: Yeah I know that I just wanted to see whether there was any option without using the chooser by default :)

Comment: It is not possible to bypass the chooser if the link is auto-verified.